# In an Excel spreadsheet with two columns A & B how to remove duplicate entries from col. B?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Given column A & B which both have email addresses how can I set up a preferably repeatable macro or VBA script that will remove all rows whose values exist in col. A from col. B? I am very inexperienced with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

you'll find here a simple VBA code.

Function DoublesDel()
    Dim mail_tmp As String

```
DernLigneA = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
DernLigneB = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To DernLigneA
    mail_tmp = LCase(Trim(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)))
    For j = 1 To DernLigneB
        If StrComp(LCase(Trim(Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2))), mail_tmp, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            'if same text founded, raz
            Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2) = ""
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

End Function

I think it's thats you need ?

Derf

Answer (score 0):

What version of Excel are you using?

You may be able to use the Remove Duplicates feature if you are using Excel 2007 and above.  If you go this route, I would strongly recommend making a duplicate of your worksheet if Remove Duplicates does not work correctly on your data.

Comment: 2010; but Remove Duplicates doesn't do what I need. I don't know what the hell it does, but it won't remove duplicate values from column B no matter which column(s) I check.